# Laravel query builder or eloquent for calculating MAU with created_at and deleted_at

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I have two tables `users` and `login_histories`

**users**

| id | name | created_at | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USER1 | 2022-10-10 0:00:00 | 2023-01-10 0:00:00 |
| 2 | USER2 | 2022-11-10 0:00:00 | NULL |
| 3 | USER3 | 2022-12-10 0:00:00 | NULL |

**login_histories**

| id | user_id | login_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-10-10 0:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-11-12 0:00:00 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-11-10 0:00:00 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-12-07 0:00:00 |
| 5 | 3 | 2022-12-10 0:00:00 |

**results**

| year | month | user_count | login_user_count | mau |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022 | 11 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022 | 12 | 3 | 2 | 0.67 |
| 2023 | 01 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

`user_count`: count of members (of year-month)

`login_user_count`: count of members logged (of year-month)

`mau = login_user_count/user_count`

I'd like to get a query for the `results`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to get mau? Not calculating?

Comment: I'd like to get a query to get  ```results```. thanks

Comment: are you going to provide any date in your query? or just pulling the result direclty without any input data?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
 $results = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('login_histories', function ($join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'login_histories.user_id')
                ->where('login_histories.created_at', '<=', now());
        })
        ->select(
            DB::raw('YEAR(login_histories.created_at) as year'),
            DB::raw('MONTH(login_histories.created_at) as month'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) as user_count'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT login_histories.user_id) as login_user_count'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT login_histories.user_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) as mau')
        )
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('users.created_at', '<=', now())
                ->orWhereNull('users.created_at');
        })
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('users.deleted_at', '>=', now())
                ->orWhereNull('users.deleted_at');
        })
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(login_histories.created_at), MONTH(login_histories.created_at)'))
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('YEAR(login_histories.created_at), MONTH(login_histories.created_at)'))
        ->get();
```

EDIT: This is what you want.

This returns

| year | month | user_count | login_user_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| year | month | number of users | login user count number |

Comment: You didn't consider  ```deleted_at``` of ```user```table.

Comment: Why do you want to consider it? Because Login History must be counted, despite a user being deleted, if logged in that month, must count.

Comment: I just edited with all you need! I tested my solution.